# starting a class with View parameter from onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android, class, view

i want to start a class with View parameter
i cannot explain it well but here is my class

```
public void presentActivity(View view)
{
    ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
            (this,view,"transition");

    int revealX = (int) (view.getX() + view.getWidth() / 2);
    int revealY = (int) (view.getY() + view.getHeight()/ 2);

    Intent search = new Intent(this,search_activity.class);
    search.putExtra(search_activity.EXTRA_CIRCULAR_REVEAL_X,revealX);
    search.putExtra(search_activity.EXTRA_CIRCULAR_REVEAL_Y, revealY);

    ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, search, activityOptionsCompat.toBundle());
}
```

just i need to know how to start presentActivity from

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

please help me , really need a way to do this;
thanks.

Comment: What is view in your function?

Comment: Its the menuitem which the x , y axis are going to be taken by presentActivity and start animation from menuItem place